# How to merge lists by id in Immutable.js?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have an immutable list of people that was created using JSON received from the server. I now update one of the people by sending an AJAX request. The response from the server returns the updated person. How do I update the immutable list with the updated person. My attempt below simply replaces the list element by index which yields an incorrect result. I want it to replace by person id.

```
var Immutable = require('immutable');

// Get me all my people
var peopleResponse = [
    { username: 'jsmith', title: 'Manager',  dept: 'Engineering', salary: 100000 },
    { username: 'lwhite', title: 'Manager',  dept: 'Sales',       salary:  90000 }
];

// Convert to immutable structures
var people = Immutable.fromJS(peopleResponse);
console.log(people);

// Change lwhite's salary to 100,000
var updateResponse =
    { username: 'lwhite', title: 'Manager',  dept: 'Sales',       salary: 100000 }

var updatedPeople = [ Immutable.fromJS(updateResponse) ];

people = people.merge(updatedPeople);
console.log(people);
```

Output:

```
List [ Map { "username": "jsmith", "title": "Manager", "dept": "Engineering", "salary": 100000 }, Map { "username": "lwhite", "title": "Manager", "dept": "Sales", "salary": 90000 } ]
List [ Map { "username": "lwhite", "title": "Manager", "dept": "Sales", "salary": 100000 }, Map { "username": "lwhite", "title": "Manager", "dept": "Sales", "salary": 90000 } ]
```

Note that the updated list has two `lwhite`s!

Comment: *How do I update the immutable list with the updated person.* sorry, but how can you update the immutable list?

Comment: To clarify, I did not mean literally. What I meant was to get a new list with updated person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came up with the following solution. It is inspired by [normalizr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36551008/how-to-merge-lists-by-id-in-immutable-js). The basic concept is that the list of people is simply an array of usernames. The actual people objects will be sitting in a map that is keyed by username.

```
var Immutable = require('immutable');

// Get me all my people
var peopleResponse = {
    result: ['jsmith', 'lwhite'],
    entities: {
        people: {
            jsmith: { username: 'jsmith', title: 'Manager',  dept: 'Engineering', salary: 100000 },
            lwhite: { username: 'lwhite', title: 'Manager',  dept: 'Sales',       salary:  90000 }
        }
    }
};

// Convert to immutable structures
var people = Immutable.fromJS(peopleResponse.result);
var peopleByUsername = Immutable.fromJS(peopleResponse.entities.people);
console.log(people);
console.log(peopleByUsername);

// Change lwhite's salary to 100,000
var updateResponse = {
    lwhite: { username: 'lwhite', title: 'Manager',  dept: 'Sales',       salary: 100000 }
};

var updatedPeopleByUsername = Immutable.fromJS(updateResponse);

peopleByUsername = peopleByUsername.merge(updatedPeopleByUsername);

console.log(people);
console.log(peopleByUsername);
```